# Reportlab csv to pdf conversion "invalid data type" error

Tags: python, csv, pdf, reportlab

Below is a script i have for a project of mine which would convert a csv report into a pdf file for easy correspondence. I used reportlab as it allows me to customise and specify how i want the pdf file to look in the end:

```
import csv
import datetime
from reportlab.lib.units import cm, inch
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import *
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
import codecs

# Data from CSV
with codecs.open('report_prototype_excel1.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader((l.replace('\0', '') for l in csvfile)) 
    elements = []

# PDF Text
# PDF Text - Styles
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleNormal = styles['Normal']

# PDF Text - Content
line1 = 'ABC Company Internal Audit Department'
line2 = 'Date: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y"))
line3 = 'Audit Number: 1'
line4 = 'This is the final report of the annual internal audit caried out by'
line5 = 'an independent auditor of the ABC Company Internal Audit Department'
line6 = 'on {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y"))

elements.append(Paragraph(line1, styleNormal))
elements.append(Paragraph(line2, styleNormal))
elements.append(Paragraph(line3, styleNormal))
elements.append(Spacer(inch, .25 * inch))
elements.append(Paragraph(line4, styleNormal))
elements.append(Paragraph(line5, styleNormal))
elements.append(Paragraph(line6, styleNormal))
elements.append(Spacer(inch, .25 * inch))

# PDF Table
# PDF Table - Styles
# [(start_column, start_row), (end_column, end_row)]
all_cells = [(0, 0), (-1, -1)]
header = [(0, 0), (-1, 0)]
column0 = [(0, 0), (0, -1)]
column1 = [(1, 0), (1, -1)]
column2 = [(2, 0), (2, -1)]
column3 = [(3, 0), (3, -1)]
column4 = [(4, 0), (4, -1)]
column5 = [(5, 0), (5, -1)]
column6 = [(6, 0), (6, -1)]
column7 = [(7, 0), (7, -1)]
column8 = [(8, 0), (8, -1)]

table_style = TableStyle([
    ('VALIGN', all_cells[0], all_cells[1], 'TOP'),
    ('LINEBELOW', header[0], header[1], 1, colors.black),
    ('ALIGN', column0[0], column0[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column1[0], column1[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column2[0], column2[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column3[0], column3[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column4[0], column4[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column5[0], column5[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column6[0], column6[1], 'LEFT'),   
    ('ALIGN', column7[0], column7[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column8[0], column8[1], 'LEFT'),

])

# PDF Table - Column Widths
colWidths = [
    
    0.4 * cm,  # column 0
    2.0 * cm,  # Column 1
    6.0 * cm,  # Column 2
    1.0 * cm,  # Column 3
    2.0 * cm,  # Column 4
    2.0 * cm,  # Column 5
    2.0 * cm,  # Column 6
    1.0 * cm,  # Column 7
    1.0 * cm,  # Column 8

]

# Add table to elements
t = Table(data, colWidths=colWidths)
t.setStyle(table_style)
elements.append(t)

# Generate PDF
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
    'report_prototype_pdf1.pdf',
    pagesize=letter,
    rightMargin=40,
    leftMargin=40,
    topMargin=40,
    bottomMargin=28)
doc.build(elements)
print('Internal Audit Report Generated!')
```

However i keep having issues with this block of code here, with the resulting errors pointing to the first line in the block here:

```
# Add table to elements
t = Table(data, colWidths=colWidths)
t.setStyle(table_style)
elements.append(t)
```

The error is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValueError("%s invalid data type" % self.identity())
ValueError: <Table@0x2579D5FA1C0 unknown rows x unknown cols>... invalid data type
```

Unfortunately, i have had not much luck troubleshooting the faulty code even after searching online for solutions and trying some solutions out. Is there a solution to my predicament?

Edit 1:
Below is a requested sample of report_prototype_excel1.csv
[Link included as i don't ave enough reputation unfortunately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPeR6.png)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a few rows from `report_prototype_excel1.csv` that would cause the problem to occur? We could then recreate the problem.

Comment: I've done it sorry for the late reply

Comment: I can't copy/paste a picture to make a CSV file, please just use the original CSV text